# Adding a canvas-sprite object to a canvas?

Tags: html, animation, canvas, sprite

I've been playing around with HTML5 and canvas and sprites and I've managed to get myself a bit stumped. I was wonderring if there was anyone out there with just a bit more experience than me who could help me 'tune' this (and also make it work).

I've got all the code up on GitHub https://github.com/AlexChesser/jsSprite and have put a live demo up over here http://chesser.ca/jsSprite

What you can see from Test 01 and 02 is that I'm able to send the Minotaur directly to the on-page canvas, I'm able to animate the Minotaur on the canvas... but when I try to create the Minotaur and add it to another canvas - I'm getting a blank screen.

(attempting to implement https://github.com/AlexChesser/jsSprite/blob/master/03-animated_minotaur_on_canvas.php)

I know it must be something small and sill that I'm doing wrong here, but I've been staring at it for hours and I can't track down the problem.

I thought I'd try posting up here to see if there's anyone who can see it 'in one go' *AND* to maybe let me know if there's anything I can do better.

If you're interested in getting a little further under the hood on this stuff, the lion's share of the code for this is coming from a Blog post http://www.johnegraham2.com/web-technology/html-5-canvas-tag-sprite-animation-demo/

Anyways, maybe it's one of those things that "comes to you" once you've walked away from the problem for a little bit.  Fingers crossed I can either figure it out or someone out ther ecan give me that little push in the right direction.

Thanks! 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stepped through your code.

`MainContext.drawImage(m.canvas, 0, 0, m.width, m.height);`

is occuring before `drawFrame` gets called because the image isn't ready yet.

So the mainContext.drawImage is drawing a canvas that has nothing painted on it yet.

Then the Sprite's canvas is loaded and ready to go, but its too late!

For confirmation, you can call `MainContext.drawImage(m.canvas, 0, 0, m.width, m.height);` in the browser console and you will see the minotaur appear.

Comment: So I've got to add a callback somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As Simon Sarris said, you are drawing the canvas too soon. What you'll need to do is either loop until the sprite is ready, or add a callback to your sprite that is called after it draws.

You already have a function attached to the image's onload event, you should be okay to do something similar for the whole sprite.

Comment: thanks, I've added some code that at the very least gets it on the page. I've pushed to git so you can see it working.